# How to use RIDE with Robot Framework implemented in jython?

Tags: automation, jython, robotframework

Our Automation framework is implemented using the Robot Framework in Jython, can anyone suggest how I can use RIDE for writing my testcases. Currently I am using  Eclipse as an editor.

Answer (score 2):

**RIDE and RobotFramework are two different things.** RIDE is an IDE (Robot IDE) which talks to the Framework. If you want to use RIDE to create your testcases just download and install RIDE, and then run them within RIDE.

But because you're already using an IDE, just run the tests outside within a terminal using:

```
jybot TestCase.robot
```

or

```
robot TestCase.robot
```

You don't need RIDE in order to use the Robot Framework. They are two seperate things.

**EDIT**

According to the Git page of [RIDE](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/Installation-Instructions) it states that:

> RIDE runs only on the regular Python, not on Jython nor IronPython. Python 2.6 is the minimum version. Notice that similarly as Robot Framework, RIDE does not yet support Python 3. Notice also that on OS X RIDE requires 32-bit Python version.

So - in your case - you will not be able to use RIDE as you are working on a Jython Environment. If you want to absolutely use RIDE, you will have to switch over to Python. I would recommend Python 2.7.x

Answer (score 0):

As clearly stated by @Goralight, the IDE and Robot Framework are two different topics. The IDE is used to Create the Robot files, RBF is used to Execute those Robot files.

An IDE like RIDE will also have functionality to start RBF from within the IDE but that is just a replacement of the commands mentioned by @Goralight. So in that sense it's an automation, not an integral part of the IDE.

Just as a side note, in case you're inan Eclpse based situation to have a closer look at [RED](https://github.com/nokia/RED) that is a full featured IDE that can be loaded into your existing Eclipse instance as a Marketplace feature or as a full separate standalone download from GitHub.